# Does this limit holding for all $T$ force pairwise equalities?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have four sequences of non-negative functions on the integers: $g^{(n)}_1,g^{(n)}_2, f^{(n)}_1, f^{(n)}_2$.

For any fixed $n$, both $f^{(n)}_1$ and $f^{(n)}_2$ are non-increasing and satisfy the constraint $\sum_{i=0}^\infty f^{(n)}_1 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty f^{(n)}_2 = 1$. For each $n$ there is an $N(n)$ defined as being the largest $N$ such that $f^{(n)}_1(i< N) = f^{(n)}_2(i< N)>0$. $N(n)$ is non-decreasing as a function of $n$.

For any fixed $n$, both $g^{(n)}_1$ and $g^{(n)}_2$ are non-decreasing.

I know that for all positive integers $T$ that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-T g^{(n)}_1(i)} f^{(n)}_1(i)}{\sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-T g^{(n)}_2(i)} f^{(n)}_2(i)} = 1$$

Are the above conditions enough to guarantee $\lim_{n \to \infty} (g^{(n)}_1(i) - g^{(n)}_2(i)) = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} (f^{(n)}_1(i) - f^{(n)}_2(i)) = 0$ for all $i < \lim_{n \to \infty} N(n)$?

---

Here's a rough motivation. Consider the case where my sums above only had a single term ($N(n)=1$). I would then define $$a_n(T) \equiv  \frac{e^{-T g^{(n)}_1(0)} f^{(n)}_1(0)}{ e^{-T g^{(n)}_2(0)} f^{(n)}_2(0)} =  \frac{f^{(n)}_1(0)}{f^{(n)}_1(1)}e^{-T(g^{(n)}_1(0)-g^{(n)}_2(0))}$$
and note that we have a nice simplification when considering ratios of $a$'s:
$$\frac{a_n(2)}{a_n(1)} = e^{-(g^{(n)}_1(0)-g^{(n)}_2(0))}$$
The statement $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n(T) = 1$ then implies $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n(2)}{a_n(1)}=1,$$ so we indeed enjoy $\lim_{n \to \infty} (g^{(n)}_1(0) - g^{(n)}_2(0)) = 0$.

This, together with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n(1) = 1$, implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f^{(n)}_1(0)}{f^{(n)}_1(1)} = 1$. In turn, since my $f^{(n)}_{1},f^{(n)}_{2} \leq 1$, we enjoy $\lim_{n \to \infty} (f^{(n)}_1(0) -f^{(n)}_1(1)) = 0$.

For the case of just a single term in the sum, I really only needed $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n(T) = 1$ for $T=1,2$.

I recognize that my desired statement is a strong one when I have many terms in the sum, and I'd be happy to see a counterexample, but I'm hopeful that the assumptions are strong enough to pull through.